# Paypal sdk- INSTRUMENT_DECLINE ERROR

Tags: android, paypal

I integrate paypal android sdk into my android aps as according to the

github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md

I created paypal aps through

developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps which provides me sandbox client id and live client id.

Everything works fine, when

```
private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()

    // Start with mock environment.  When ready, switch to sandbox (ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
    // or live (ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
    .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
    .clientId("<sandbox cliend id>");
```

But when I switch to `PaypalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION` and `clientId` to live client id , it gives me error :

```
{"name":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","message":"The instrument presented  was either declined by the processor or bank, or it can't be used for this payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","debug_id":"bd919720c3913"}
09-29 09:53:35.107: E/PayPalService(4811): INSTRUMENT_DECLINED
```

I did not find the information about the error in https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INSTRUMENT_DECLINED as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be issue with the buyer's PayPal account . You need to make sure that the buyer has the funding source attached to his PayPal account like credit card or the verified bank account . "Instrument" here refers to the funding source attached to the PayPal account .

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the funding instrument, like maybe a credit card, present in the buyer's PayPal account was declined.